# Finding solution sets for logarithmic equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponential-function

Is there any way to find the solution set, by hand, for

> $7\log_{10}x=x-2$

I know $x\ge0$ and this is equivalent to $x^7=10^{x-2}$. I am aware I can simply graph $y=x^7$ and $y=10^{x-2}$ respectively, and then find when the lines intersect. Unfortunately, this would require a graphing calculator.

Are there any techniques I can possibly use by hand to find the solution set here?

Comment: Well...the solutions (numerically computed) are $ 0.639131,  8.50923$, nothing especially pleasant.  You can write the solutions in terms of the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) but that's basically a tautology.

Comment: Whenever transcendental functions (e.g. $\log,\tan,\sinh$) are involved there's usually no getting around using numerical methods (e.g. a graphing calculator or Wolfram Alpha) to solve them.

Comment: ^ to expound: That’s why they’re called transcendental and have special names.

Comment: Lamberts W function.

Answer (score 1):

*Without graphing calculator and not using Lambert function.*

Consider that you look for the zero's of function
$$f(x)=7\log_{10}(x)-x+2$$ for which
$$f'(x)=\frac{7}{x \log (10)}-1\qquad \text{and} \qquad f''(x)=-\frac{7}{x^2 \log (10)} < 0\,\, \forall x$$
The first derivative cancels at
$$x_*=\frac{7}{\log (10)} \approx 3.04\implies f(x_*)\approx 2.34$$ and this point is a maximum.

Now, by inspection, 
$$f\left(\frac{1}{10}\right)=-\frac{51}{10} \qquad \qquad f(1)=1 \qquad\qquad  f(10)=-1$$ So, we have two roots such that
$$\frac{1}{10} < x_1 < 1\qquad \qquad 1 < x_2 <10$$

Now, let us use Newton method which, starting with a guess $x_0$, will update it according to
$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$ To avoid overshoot of the solution, by Darboux theorem, since $f''(x) < 0$, let us start from a value $x_0$ such that $f(x_0) <0$; notice that we have these points.

Below are reproduced the iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 0.100000 \\
 1 & 0.273466 \\
 2 & 0.492423 \\
 3 & 0.617296 \\
 4 & 0.638658 \\
 5 & 0.639131
\end{array}
\right)$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 10.0000 \\
 1 & 8.56321 \\
 2 & 8.50933 \\
 3 & 8.50923
\end{array}
\right)$$